# Jest - Cannot find module 'xxx' from 'xxx'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tsconfig

I have a `react` app and when I try to run a simple test, it cannot find files called in the component.

In the app, everyhing works fine. It is only with jest test that I have this error.

Any idea how to tell `jest` to have same config as `tsconfig` ?

Here is the import that fails in the component tested :

```
import socialMediaToComponent from "ui/configs/socialMediaToComponent";
```

Here is my test :

```
describe("SocialMediaArea", () => {
    it("should display specific social media links", () => {
        render(<SocialMedias />);
[...]
```

`tsconfig` :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
[...]
```

`jest.config` :

```
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    verbose: true,
    rootDir: `src/`,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(jpg|png|webp|css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__tests__/mocks/mockAssets/mockEmpty.ts",
        "\\.svg": "<rootDir>/__tests__/mocks/mockAssets/mockReactComponents.ts",
    },
    testMatch: ["**/*.test.tsx"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/__tests__/setupTest.ts"],
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Try `npm run jest --clearCache`

Comment: Still same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Put it here in case it helps.
I added in my `jest.config.ts` :

```
import { compilerOptions } from '/app/tsconfig.json'

[...]
modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
```